# What happens when you get a site that uses MySQL online?

Tags: mysql, database, web, website-hosting

I have created a site that uses MySQL and I want to get it online.

My question is:

- What happens with the database that I created?
- Will it automatically be saved in the host?
- Will all the tables etc. remain the same?

Also, I have created an update module which connects to the database to store new data.

What happens in than case?

If anyone knows details about the whole process.

Please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use local database for development, you need to export database from local database and import them into the database of your hosing provider or any other online database.

If you developed your site using the online database like database provided by the hosting site, there will be data and database as it is.

In your case the database is stored locally. So every change you make during development will be reflected only if your local database is imported to online database.

Comment: Thanks! I actually used local database! Is it difficult to export it and import it into the hosting provider’s database?

Comment: It is very easy to export and import if you have phpmyadmin

Comment: Do you maybe know what happens with all the libraries my code uses? Are they going to automatically be imported in the online site?